# onclick event in anchor tag not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, anchor

The following works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE 8 will not call the submit() method when the anchor link is clicked.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submit();">Sign In</a>
```

The submit method is defined on the same page as follows:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submit()
{
// other code                                              
document.forms[0].submit();
}  

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: did you try onclick="javascript:submit();" ?

Comment: @Umair: There's no need for the `javascript:` prefix on `onclick` or similar event handler attributes. This isn't the `href`.

Comment: once it had worked for me so I guess it is

Comment: @Umair: With respect, it must have been something else. In that location, `javascript:` is a label (and one you're not using), not a protocol. In the `href`, it would be a protocol.

Comment: maybe stupid question: is there a form? :) or are there more than one?

Comment: If you change the `submit()` function to

    function submit() {                                           
      alert('it works');
    }

What happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you provide a bit more context? Such as where and how the `submit` function is defined? With just the above, it should work -- except:

You probably also want to `return false;` in there though, to cancel the default action. E.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submit();return false;">Sign In</a>
```

It may be that the default action is happening immediately after the `submit` and interfering with it.

**Edit**: Just for fits and giggles, try using a different name for your `submit` function. IE has namespacing issues. If you have anything with the `id` or `name` attribute set to "submit", for instance, that could be an issue...

Comment: I tried adding "return false;" with no effect.  The IE debugger shows the call to the onclick code, but won't enter the submit() method.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not sure I know what you mean by the debugger showing it entering the `onclick` code but not entering the `submit` method. Is there an exception thrown? If not, what happens such that it "won't" enter the function?

Comment: Thanks for responding T.J.  It's odd really.  I set the IE 8 debugger to "break on all".  As soon as I click the "Sign In" link, the debugger breaks and highlights onclick="submit();" in the anchor.  I assume the highlighting is to indicate the next instruction to be executed.  To be safe, I also set a breakpoint inside the submit method.  From this point I click "Step Into" or "Step Over" on the debugger menu.  Both have the same effect of highlighting the void(0) method.  For some reason IE will not execute the submit() function.  I don't see any indication of an error.

Comment: You were right T.J.  It was a name space conflict.  IE uses submit for something.  Once I changed the function name it worked.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Mark: Excellent! Glad that helped, I should have thought of it to start with.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I faced the same namespace problem with <a onclick="click()"><\a> function. Once I changed the function name things worked. Thanks for this conversation.

Answer (score 3):

For others who have come across this problem more recently, for me it was due to IE 11 using **compatibility mode** on the site. It saw I was on the same domain, assumed the site was an intranet site and automatically switched to compatibility mode which broke some of the Javascript (and caused some other unexpected display issues).

You can turn off this 'feature' by clicking on the settings cog and choosing "Compatibility View Settings". There is a tick box that was set called "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<a onclick="submit();">Sign In</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:submit();">Sign In</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to input the value to the javascript function, make sure that uses the single quotation instead of the double quotation.

For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="your_function('input');">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: This did not work for me in ie9. I had to shift to jquery