# onclick function returns undefined in IE, works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a HTML page like this (simplified)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
...
    </style>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
      function foo()
      {
...
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="ClickMe" onClick="foo()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but when I use IE, when I click, it returns 'foo' is undefined in the console logs.
I tried moving all  section inside  but still got the same issue.
Any hints?

EDIT 1 : here is more of my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"/>
    <title>My Title</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleBrowseClick()
      {
        var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
        fileinput.click();
      }

      function handleChange()
      {
        var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
      }

      function addListener()
      {
        document.getElementById('browse').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
      }

      function handleFileSelect(evt)
      {
        var files = evt.target.files;

        var output = [];
        for (var i=0 ; f=files[i] ; i++) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
              <more JS code here>
            };
          })(f);
          reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" style="display: none" onChange="handleChange();"/>
    <input type="button" value="ClickMe" id="fakeBrowse" onClick="handleBrowseClick();"/>
    <output id="list"></output>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = addListener();
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the space after `type`, IE must consider the script type is empty and doesn't parse it as JS. But that's still terrible code.

Comment: This seems extremely dubious. You should post your actual code.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy,yeah..true

Comment: It works for me same format of your code

Comment: @Pointy my actual code is 46,000 lines

Comment: @Capsule I removed the space but still the same problem

Comment: @rh4games well the code you posted does not have the problem you describe.

Comment: It is impossible to help you with what is provided.

Comment: @epacscarello I added EDIT 1 with more of my code. IHTH

Comment: @rh4games Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @X.Liu I am using IE 11

Comment: @rh4games Your code in Edit 1 works for me on my IE 11 on Windows 10.

Comment: @X.Liu Thanks for trying. It is not working for me with IE 11 on Windows 7 Enterprise. Works fine with Chrome and FireFox on the same machine !

Comment: Well, I have the exact same trouble, a simple button onclick function is working on Chrome, Firefox, but does not working on IE...

Answer (score 1):

I had just came across the same problem.

For me, it was because the HTML had some syntax errors that Chrome (even Microsoft Edge) doesn't complain about but Internet Explorer does.

As soon as I fixed those the undefined function error was gone.

Comment: We can't consider this as an answer, it is just an advice from you. please modify your answer to include a realistic solution to the question problem as you can see we can't assume that every problem is a syntax error problem but instead you need to search in supported browsers and search for IE problems related to the problem asked. please modify your answer.

Comment: This is totally true. This is just a suggestion to anyone who might have faced the same problem and what *might* be the case for him too. I wanted to add it as a comment but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first hit in google for my query, but no actual answer was given:

I'll give a reference to where I found the actual solution:
[onclick event in anchor tag not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653722/onclick-event-in-anchor-tag-not-working-in-ie)

which points out that IE is stupid, and needs you to change:

```
onClick="somefunc();"
```

to

```
onClick="javascript:somefunc();"
```

Comment: This was the first comment on the question itself "did you try onclick="javascript:submit();" ?" from @Umair